# drag and drop without moving the element

Tags: jquery-ui

Hi am using drag and drop from Jquery, and what I want to try and simulate is the drag and drop except during the drag motion I don't want the element to actually move from its place.

In the example here : http://jsfiddle.net/2LN5G/ when you drag the "Drag me to target" it is moved from the possition and reverts back when it is dropped. I want to still show "Drag me to target in the current position and still show the "Drag me to target" moving with the cursor. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the **visual feedback** example on [jQueryUI.com](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback).

Basically, you want to specify the helper option when calling the `.draggable()` method.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  helper: "clone"
});
```

Comment: Hi Simshaun, Perfect thank you very much!I'll mark this as answered in 9 mins :D